# Manga where Norse and Japanese gods are incarnating

Tags: story-identification, manga

It's quite an old manga, I think, where you have God incarnate as a story. I remember it had Nordic gods such as Loki, Odin and Thor in western territory and Japanese gods such as Amaterasu, Susano'o, etc... They can become the God incarnate when passing certain portals to otherworld. I remember the MC is Minamoto no Yoshitsune Reincarnate? While the heroine is west God incarnate.

Comment: My impulse, based on a bit of Googling around, is the manga adaptation of *Fate Grand Order*, but I haven't found enough details.

Comment: Do you remember what the incarnated gods do? Go to school together? Fight with humans in a tournament? Fight frost giants? If they become gods after going through portals, are they regular humans before then? Is this a temporary thing, or do they permanently become gods?

Comment: *God Is Dead* matches this trope quite well

Answer (score -1):

I think it's called raisenkamika if I'm not mistaken

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you mean *Raise kamika*?  You should add some details about the story, and maybe some links, so it's obvious how it matches the question.